# Server-side application fails to run command

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET application that is already deployed in an Azure virtual machine. The situation is as follows:

This application, **OCREngine**, is deployed on the server along with other 3rd party applications. OCREngine is executed on the server by using a service reference to the web service. **It runs fine most of the time.** But there is one exception: one of the branches of execution won't run the program it needs to run. Both of the branches have to run a program (both are being run in the same way), but one works and the other one doesn't.

This one works: **CleanJPEG.exe**

```cs
proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "CleanJPEG.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + tempPages + "Color Info.JPEG\"";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.Start();
```

And this one doesn't: **cpctool.exe**

```cs
proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cpctool.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + file + "\" -o \"" + tempPages + "page.tiff\"";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.Start();
```

They are both in the same folder, which has full permissions for the AppPool and so does %TEMP%.

If I run the application from the server, everything works fine. But when I run it through the web service, an instance of cpctool.exe gets created (can be seen on Background processes in the task manager) but it doesn't do it's job. And thus the execution of OCREngine never finishes.

This last part is what made me think it was a problem with permissions, but I don't know what else to give permissions to.

I run [Folder Changes View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/folder_changes_view.html) on cpctool.exe and it showed access to the folder where the files are stored and one file being saved in %TEMP% (which, funny enough, doesn't appear when running Folder Changes View on the server).

Can anyone think of any special folder that needs permission that I might be forgetting?

Comment: 1) reason: may be you have to give full file path.
2) you have to make sure all argument is properly Escaped.

Comment: If a a process starts and does nothing, then it's probably madde only for interactive use, and is prompting  for something. Looking at this page: http://www.oncenter.com/kbase/article/AA-00296/0/OST-CPC-File-Support.html it says   _The FIRST TIME the CPCTool.exe runs the user is prompted to read/accept a User Agreement from Cartesian – this agreement MUST be accepted or the converter will not work._  I reckon thats what it's doing

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid That's probably it... I had forgotten about that. Now I need to find a way to accept that licence =]

Comment: You need to log in interactively as your application pool user and run it and hope that whatever convoluted arcane registration method it uses will work

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Do you want to put that in an answer? That was the exact problem, heh. Just solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are completely correct to concentrrate on the permissions as that is *usually* the issue.

If an EXE process starts and does nothing, then it's probably only made for interactive use, and is prompting for something.

Looking at [this page](http://oncenter.com/kbase/article/AA-00296/0/OST-CPC-File-Support.h%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Btml) it says:

> The FIRST TIME the CPCTool.exe runs the user is prompted to read/accept a User Agreement from Cartesian – this agreement MUST be accepted or the converter will not work.

I reckon that's what it's doing. Try logging in as the application pool user, start the program and accept the agreement.